# Youtube video thumbnail issue. Black space on top and bottom of the image

Tags: wordpress

I have a [site](http://www.stresssmashers.com) that uses thumbnail images from youtube videos. In other words, the image you get , when you hover over a video, right click on it and save image as. The issue is that there is black space above and below the video thumbnail image.

I could crop it each time in imageready or fireworks, but I was wondering if there is a way perhaps some css code that I could cut off the image from the bottom and top, cutting out the black space. Unless the black space is ingrained as part of the image!

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks

Omar

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem here. The thumbnail have 120x90 pixels, 4x3 format (1,333 aspect ratio). It seems the video being wide aspect ratio, YT generate these black bars.

With CSS we can use the "background-position" property to set a thumbnail image as background of a  and them calculating -11px to hide the top bar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220715/removing-black-borders-43-on-youtube-thumbnails