# Google Drive API v3 for iOS : How to get thumbnails?

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

In the past, with Google Drive API v2, I could easily get thumbnails for pictures or videos with the property `thumbnailLink` on `GTLDriveFile`.

But now, with the API v3 which I currently use with Swift, the `thumbnailLink` of the files I get from Google Drive is nil, so what can I do to get thumbnails of images and videos stored in the user's Google Drive. I need to display theses in my iOS app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to specify `thumbnailLink` in fields, such as

```
let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()
query.fields = "files(id, name, thumbnailLink)"
```

then you can access the property `thumbnailLink` for images and videos

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use the Drive REST API method [`Files: get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get). The result of that method contains `thumbnailLink` but according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files) it is 'a short-lived link to the file's thumbnail. Typically lasts on the order of hours.

Alternatively, you can cache the thumbnail in your application, reducing the count of drive api requests and thus improve your page performance. You need to fetch the information for the uploaded file. The easiest way of caching is to simply download the thumbnail and save it like `fileid_thumb` somewhere and upon the next request, you check if such a file exists before actually requesting the thumbnail. Check [here](http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=33009056&s=Lawyer&ttl=How+to+show+thumbnail+image+in+my+project+when+i+am+storing+image+on+google+drive) the detailed explanation.

You can also upload a thumbnail by setting the [`contentHints.thumbnail`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/file#uploading_thumbnails) property on the [File resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files) during an insert or update call as follows:

- Set `contentHints.thumbnail.image` to the URL-safe Base64-encoded image (see [RFC 4648 section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5))
- Set `contentHints.thumbnail.mimeType` to the appropriate type for the image format

You can also check the accepted answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268432/get-make-thumbnail-image-from-video-url-getting-in-api-response).

Hope this helps!