# Crop images proportionally in responsive design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

So I have YouTube video thumbnails displayed on a website, but they seem to have letterboxing at the top and bottom. I need to crop this, but I can't just crop x many pixels because of the reponsive design.

How would I crop images dynamically based on their width? Would I have to do it using Javascript during resize? Or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: You could use [16:9 YouTube thumbnails](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18979282/331137) to get rid of the vast majority of the bars by just not having them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by drawing the image to a canvas, iterating through rows of pixels and checking if they were black. The first time a colored pixel was detected marked the edge of the letterbox. I used this information to crop the image and draw it to another canvas.

It's not a perfect solution, but it worked for me. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`object-fit`](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/object-fit/) css but [it's not full browser compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit), however a [polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit) exist

Else you can use div with background-image and [`background-size`](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/background-size/) with `cover` or `contain`, that have a [better support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)