# Vimeo full screen videos with no black bars

Tags: video, jquery-plugins, fullscreen, vimeo

I´m trying to find some plugin or method to embed Vimeo videos as fullscreen backgrounds and "full div/wrapper" that displays the videos with no black bars as well.

Do you know some method for this? I´m searching for something similar to this plugin - http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-ytplayer/

Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794000/removing-black-borders-on-a-vimeo-iframe-embed-using-css/19801191#19801191

Also: http://fitvidsjs.com/

Comment: fitvids.js is not a solution in this case, but thank you very much anyway. I will take a try to the proposed thread. Thanks, Sean!