# overlay on top of a responsive video

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html5-video, overlay

Hi I built a responsive theme to embed vimeo videos.

Here is my CSS:

```
.vimeo-container {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.vimeo-container iframe,
.vimeo-container object,
.vimeo-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<div class="vimeo-container">
   <!-- video iframe goes here -->
</div>
```

It works well and is responsive. Now I want to keep this responsiveness but make this video look like a background, so I thought of adding an overlay with text on top of it. Something like what is done on [this Site](http://apps.npr.org/tshirt/#/title).

How to keep the responsiveness and add an overlay with text to make it similar to the mentioned site above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the overlay, you can add an absolutelty postionned DIV inside your container. I changed your CSS a bit to make it more fullscreen-like and more responsive by giving a Fixed position to the vimeo-container, because I saw that there was padding at the bottom and we could see the white background of the body.

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/IndieRok/dg5j430z/)

HTML:

```
<div class="vimeo-container">
   <div class="overlay">
       <div class="text-container">
           <h1>Hello World!</h1>
       </div>
   </div>
   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/34905657?color=0fb0d4&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="https://vimeo.com/34905657">Cowboy&#039;s Cat</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/animadetv">Animade</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vimeo-container {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.vimeo-container .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:999;
}

.vimeo-container .overlay .text-container{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.vimeo-container .overlay .text-container h1{
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.vimeo-container iframe,
.vimeo-container object,
.vimeo-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: As for the black bars on top and bottom, I've checked a few vimeo videos to validate and I do believe this is native to vimeo's code. Read the chosen answer to this post, more information about Vimeo [stackoverlow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794000/removing-black-borders-on-a-vimeo-iframe-embed-using-css)

Comment: A quick solution would be to host the video on your server and add it by using the hmtl5 video tag. This would provide a perfect fullscreen effect without the hassle of Vimeo's native black bars on top and bottom and would also hide the play/pause control. Since it's a looping video (i would assume), and it's size will be rather small, it would not demand much bandwidth from the user. Anyway, it's just a suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Since your video container already have position: relative, you can set position:absolute for you layer over video:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Here is a working fiddle exampple with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/d8w4o31k/

Also, you can take a look on this fiddle example with video playing in bg: https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/dpfzhw1v/ I used exactly this thing on one website I was working on some time ago.