# Remove black borders for a youtube embed

Tags: css, html, youtube, responsive-design

I am trying to embed a youtube video on the background of my website. I have this working and it is responsive, except that when my embed video is widescreen (16:9) but my viewport is for example square (1:1), it creates black borders to compensate for the leftover space.

[image]

I was wondering if there was an option to crop the video so that the 'center' of the video is always in the screen, just like in the example image above. The leftover parts would be cut off. I think the CSS equivalent for images would be `background-size: cover;`.

Here is the code I have at this moment. Try to make your viewport square and you will see the black borders. It's also available in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg3becj6/).

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body,html{ margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;}

        div.bg_utube {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: -99999;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #player{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bg_utube">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script>
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        var video_id = 'JQ7a_8psCn0';

        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: video_id,
                playerVars: {
                    'autoplay': 1,
                    'controls': 0,
                    'html5': 1,
                    'modestbranding': 1,
                    'showinfo': 0,
                    'related': 0},

                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
            player.mute();
            event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ) {

            }

            if(event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
                player.loadVideoById(video_id);
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I did search on google for solutions but couldn't find any. Many were specifically for `<object>` and `<embed>`, using the old youtube embed style. I'm using the YouTube API to render a HTML5 player.

Could someone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Any chance you could use the <video> tag in stead?

Comment: I don't think I have the control over the YouTube API in what way it generate the code for my video. At the moment it will become an iframe. Besides, the `<video>` tag is meant to load in a video of a supported format (which may differ by browser). YouTube embed links are not just videos, they are webpages that contain logic to detect what your user supports and how they can play the youtube video, using HTML5, or flash, or some other plugin. I'm using this because I want to support as much devices as possible. As such, I don't think `<video>` is an option.

Comment: The standard youtube embed DOES support more since <video> is html5 compatible browsers only. However, you can use a URL as a src for the video tag, and you can also make this source browser specific. 
This does not fix the issue for non HTML5 browsers however.

Comment: @user1129884 I actually only care about Firefox / Safari / Chrome / Android (default browser?) / and iPhone (Safari/Chrome). Would they all be HTML5?

Comment: If those browsers are all up to date then yes, they are all HTML5. They do all support different codecs though.
Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836015/youtube-url-in-video-tag

Comment: @user1129884 when I do get it to work with the `<video>` tag, what more options do I have or what do I need to do to achieve maintaining the aspect ratio of the video and cropping?

Comment: If you're going to use the `<video>` tag as an alternative, be aware not all video formats are supported by all browsers. H.264 seems to have most support but it's status as a free format is not certain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220715/removing-black-borders-43-on-youtube-thumbnails/42338572#42338572

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Player creates **iframe** in which the video plays with **youtube**
This represents a problem because you can not change the parameters of objects in **cross domains**. 
The object who contans video is in `player.c.contentWindow.querySelector(".video-stream.html5-main-video")`

Only solution I now is to transform container .**bg_utube** with css like this

```
div.bg_utube {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -99999;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -ms-transform: scale(2,3);
      -webkit-transform: scale(2,3);
      transform: scale(2,3);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This is obviously not the best solution, but it'll do for now until I have a better one.