# How to remove black border of Youtube image

Tags: php, css, youtube-api

I got a lot of examples here how to get Youtube image. But if video is non-standard format, for example, vertical, black frame appears on the image.

I found interesting link on this site where it can be cut by GET query:
http://img.youtube.com/vi/XkOpbLBzPsY/hqdefault.jpg

http://img.youtube.com/vi/XkOpbLBzPsY/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=Gv-oyTIgA39e7UG01pZ2RiGbwSo

.. I tried out with my image, but nothing happened, and not any info on what these parameters are for.

The question is: if we can do that as in above urls, how can I get these parameters info? If not, is there any other way to remove black frame?

Is it possible to get such clear image if we know Youtube code only?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the 16:9 [yt:aspectratio](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_media%3athumbnail) format of the youtube thumbnail. Try using the image URL provided in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220715/removing-black-borders-43-on-youtube-thumbnails):

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Tried this and it works. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I could do by:

```
<a href="#">
    <div style="background:url(<?php echo $url ?>) center no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
                height:100px;
                width:50px;">
    </div>
</a>
```

Unfortunately not with the help of youtube api.