# How to Remove Black border from youtube preview image( varying image black borders length)

Tags: youtube

I have already gone through the following links

-> [Removing black borders 4:3 on youtube thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220715/removing-black-borders-43-on-youtube-thumbnails)

-> [How to remove black border of Youtube image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890029/how-to-remove-black-border-of-youtube-image)

-> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220715/removing-black-borders-43-on-youtube-thumbnails#:~:text=To%20remove%20the%20black%20borders,which%20come%20from%20that%20domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220715/removing-black-borders-43-on-youtube-thumbnails#:%7E:text=To%20remove%20the%20black%20borders,which%20come%20from%20that%20domain).

We have many videos in our project with different size(width & height).

Tried following solutions

**Solution 1**: crop or adjust the height

```
         HTML
          <div class="thumb">
            <img src="...">
          </div>
         
         CSS
          
        .thumb {
           overflow: hidden;
         }
        .thumb img {
          margin: -10% 0;
          width: 100%;
         }            

Failing for some sceanrios , because of image black border size is varying for few images.

Screenshot for reference
```

[Image with less black border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M8GQ.png)
[Image with more black border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T4LT.png)

**Solution 2**: Use it as a background image, center it and change height.

```
    .youtubePreview {
        background:url('http://img.youtube.com/vi/aOPGepdbfpo/0.jpg') center no-repeat;
        height:204px;
        width:480px;
    }
    
    or
    
     also tried with background-image
     
     <div class="bgimg" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://img.youtube.com/vi/8yxZ-k0xI9s/0.jpg&quot;); height:275px "></div>
    
 Example: 450*275 failing       
     
We have video with different sizes so it works for some width and its failing for other widths.
```

**Solution 3:**  Get Youtube Images not having black borders ( use mqdefault.jpg instead of 0.jpg)

followed this link [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Based on above link came to know that mqdefault.jpg images not havin black borders

```
   We using url for images https://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBEVIDEOID/0.jpg 
   
   so replaced with      https://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBEVIDEOID/mqdefault.jpg
    
    
But unfortunately few mqdefault images having black borders at left and right side.''
```

[mqdefault image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi5PR.png)

1. Many videos with different sizes(height & width )
2. Preview image black border length also varying

Can anyone please give some idea how to achive this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [edit] your question and add the `video_id` you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples I adapted (*by checking the embed video and view its CSS styles*):

Example # 1:

```css
.ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image {
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p>Image 1: </p>
<div class="ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image" style="background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3TJgmUGFHqw/sddefault.jpg');"></div>
```

Example # 2:

```css
.ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image {
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p>Image 2: </p>
<div class="ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image" style="background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NNgYId7b4j0/maxresdefault.jpg');"></div>
```